# How to run BackgroundWorker process inside forloop for each interation?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

How do I work my code properly in each and every loop ?

Original code which executes only once works perfect-

Form1.cs

```
private void CreateUserClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)       
    {

            User parameters = new User
            {
                user = UserTextBox.Text + i,                         
            };


            DataWorkers.InitiateWork(sender, DataWorkers.CreateUserWorker, parameters);
        }
    }
```

code change to work for execute `CreateUserWork` 5 times in forloop which will save `username`

Form1.cs

```
private void CreateUserClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)       
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {                    
        User parameters = new User
        {
            user = UserTextBox.Text + i,                         
        };

        BackgroundWorker CreateUserWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

        CreateUserWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(Workers.CreateUserWork);

        DataWorkers.InitiateWork(sender, DataWorkers.CreateUserWorker, parameters);
    }
}
```

DataWorkers.cs

```
public class DataWorkers
{
    public static readonly BackgroundWorker CreateUserWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

    public static void StartUpLogic()
    {
        CreateAccountWorker.DoWork += CreateUserWork;
    }

    public static void InitiateWork(
        object sender,
        BackgroundWorker worker,
        WorkerParameters parameters = null)
    {
        StaticElements.InvokerButtons[worker] = new InvokerButton(sender);

        StaticElements.InvokerButtons[worker].Button.IsEnabled = false;
        StaticElements.InvokerButtons[worker].Button.Content = "Wait...";

        worker.RunWorkerAsync(parameters);
    }
}

public static void CreateUserWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
//create new user
}
```

Suggest me correct change.

Comment: Why you need background worker here? Why not just Task?

Comment: The question/problem is missing. Also, `//mystuff` is probably the most relevant piece of code.

Comment: @HenkHolterman it only save `username` .

Comment: You're always using the same background worker. `BackgroundWorker` can only run one task at a time. Just use `Task.Run` - or since it seems you're trying to do I/O here, just use asynchronous I/O; no point in wasting threads just to *wait*.

Comment: You seem to be given parameters around? Why not use that option (to make the username part of the parameters?)? I also don't really see why you would create your backgroundWorker as static?

Comment: backgrounWorker implemetation is already done for single user create so  for muItiple user create on forloop I have to do it in that way if possible , can anyone provide any sample code for that? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to resolve this without background worker.

```
private async void CreateUserClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        User parameters = new User
        {
            user = UserTextBox.Text + i,
        };

        await Task.Run(()=>CreateUserWork(parameters));
    }
}
```

where

```
CreateUserWork(User parameters)
{ 
 // your saving stuff
}
```

Comment: backgrounWorker implemetation is alrady done for single user create so I have to do it in that way if possible , can you provide any sample code for that? thanks

Comment: @Neo the best thing that you can do in that situation - is get rid from backgroungWorker. If I will try to improve your sample, Im afraid, that I will get more unclear code than its now.

Comment: oh ok can I use one main therad and inside workerBackground exceute loop something like that

Comment: have you debugged backgrondworker? How much ```CreateUserWork``` called and with which parameters?

Comment: it executes 5 times but application gets hangs up :(

Comment: so, yep, U can try to use this ```Task.Run``` inside backgroungWorker

Comment: yu mean in my case in method `public static void InitiateWork`

Comment: No, I mean use this ```Task.Run()``` inside ```DoWorkEventHandler``` or even better, inside ```CreateUserWork```